# Ramda concat array issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, ramda.js

How to concat two arrays in Ramda.js?

I have next data:

```
const inputData = {
  content: [
    {

      info: ['Test-1-1', 'test-1-2'],

      moreInfo: ['foo', 'bar'],

      firstName: 'first',

      lastName: 'lst',

      notes: 'Some info goes here'

    },
        {

      info: ['Test-2-1', 'test-2-2'],

      moreInfo: ['foo-2', 'bar-2'],

      firstName: 'first',

      lastName: 'lst',

      notes: 'Some info goes here-2'

    },
  ]
}
```

I can manipulate this data just fine, but I cannot combine two arrays into one.

What I need to do, is to take

```
info: ['Test-2-1', 'test-2-2'],
moreInfo: ['foo-2', 'bar-2'],
```

End return

```
"theInfo": ["Test-1-1", "test-1-2", "foo", "bar"]
```

My code:

```
const allInfo = (R.props(['info', 'moreInfo']));

const returnNewObject = R.applySpec({

 // More code here to do other stuff

  theInfo: allInfo,

})

R.map(returnNewObject, inputData.content)
```

What I get:

```
{
  // other info

  "theInfo": [["Test-1-1", "test-1-2"], ["foo", "bar"]]
}
```

What I've tried:

- use example from documentation

> R.concat([4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3]);

But it returns array of empty object, for some reasons it doesn't work like in the documentation

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:

```
const allInfo = R.compose(R.flatten, (R.props(['info', 'moreInfo'])))
```

End it returns flatten array:

```
["Test-1-1", "test-1-2", "foo", "bar"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly write something like this (with an additional field combination for demo purposes)L

```js
const extract = applySpec ({
  theInfo: compose (unnest, props (['info', 'moreInfo'])),
  fullName: compose (join (' '), props (['firstName', 'lastName'])),
  notes: prop ('notes')
})

const process = evolve ({
  content: map (extract)
}) 

const inputData = {content: [{info: ['Test-1-1', 'test-1-2'], moreInfo: ['foo', 'bar'], firstName: 'first', lastName: 'lst', notes: 'Some info goes here'}, {info: ['Test-2-1', 'test-2-2'], moreInfo: ['foo-2', 'bar-2'], firstName: 'first', lastName: 'lst', notes: 'Some info goes here-2'}]}

console .log (process (inputData))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script> const {applySpec, compose, unnest, props, join, prop, evolve, map} = R </script>
```

And if we had no other use for it, we could embed `extract` inside `process` like this:

```js
const process = evolve ({
  content: map (applySpec ({
    theInfo: compose (unnest, props (['info', 'moreInfo'])),
    fullName: compose (join (' '), props (['firstName', 'lastName'])),
    notes: prop('notes')
  }))
})
```

But there is a good question of how much Ramda adds to a using a vanilla JS version:

```js
const process = ({content, ...rest}) => ({
  ...rest,
  content: content.map (({info, moreInfo, firstName, lastName, notes}) => ({
    theInfo: info .concat (moreInfo),
    fullName: `${firstName} ${lastName}`,
    notes
  }))
})
```

If I was already using Ramda in my project, I would choose the slightly more declarative Ramda version; it is a close call, though.  And I certainly wouldn't add Ramda just for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **.flat** to flatten the array.

```
theInfo.flat() //["Test-1-1", "test-1-2", "foo", "bar"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but with Ramda it should work in a different way. At list in my mind :)